# Erro ao criar imagem captcha "A imagem http://localhost/projeto/index.php contem erros e não pode ser exibida"

Tags: php, captcha

estou estudando um livro no qual o codigo é o mesmo e mesmo assim não funciona alguem sabe me dizer o que poderia estar ocorrendo?

```
<?php

$pass_chars = "";
for($i = 0; $i < CAPTCHA_NUMCHARS; $i++){
    $pass_chars .= chr(rand(97, 122)); //cria um codigo de letras de com 7 caracteres
}

            //CRIA A IMAGEM
            $img = imagecreatetruecolor(CAPTCHA_WIDTH, CAPTCHA_HEIGHT);
            //DEFINE O FUNDO BRANCO COM LETRAS PRETAS E GRAFICOS CINSAS
            $bg_color = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);//branco
            $text_color = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);//preto
            $graphic_color = imagecolorallocate($img, 70, 70, 70);//cinza

            //PREENCHE O FUNDO
            imagefilledrectangle($img, 0, 0, CAPTCHA_WIDTH, CAPTCHA_HEIGHT, $bg_color);

            //INSERE ALGUMAS LINHAS ALEATORIAS    
            for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
                imageline($img, 0, rand() % CAPTCHA_HEIGHT, CAPTCHA_WIDTH, rand() % CAPTCHA_HEIGHT, $graphic_color);  
            }
            //INSERE ALGUNS PONTOS ALEATORIOS
            for($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++){
                imagesetpixel($img, rand() % CAPTCHA_HEIGHT, rand() % CAPTCHA_HEIGHT, $graphic_color);  
            }
            //DESENHA A STRING DA SENHA
                imagettftext($img, 18, 0, 5, CAPTCHA_HEIGHT - 5, $text_color, 'Courier New Bold.ttf', $pass_chars);

            //FAZ UM OUTPUT DA IMAGEM COMO JPEG, usando cabeçalho
                header("Content-type:image/png");
                imagepng($img);

                imagedestroy($img);
```

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver troquei a fonte e após algumas paginas o script do livro apresenta algo que não havia sido apresentado até então eu precisei iniciar uma sessão e colocar a variável de caracteres da imagem dentro de uma variável de sessão criptografada segue parte do codigo corrigido

`<?php
session_start();
    $pass_chars = "";
    for($i = 0; $i < CAPTCHA_NUMCHARS; $i++){
        $pass_chars .= chr(rand(97, 122)); //cria um codigo de letras de com 7 caracteres
    }
//arnazena a senha criptografada em uma variavel de sessão
                $_SESSION['pass_chars'] = sha1($pass_chars);
                //CRIA A IMAGEM
                $img = imagecreatetruecolor(CAPTCHA_WIDTH, CAPTCHA_HEIGHT);` ...